# Is there a way to combine the results of array_count_values($arr1) and array_count_values($arr2) if $arr1 and $arr2 have elements with the same value?

Tags: php, linux, unix

Is there an efficient way to combine the return arrays of `array_count_values($arr1)` and `array_count_values($arr2)` if `$arr1` and `$arr2` have elements with the same value?

I'm trying to work through the classical "generate the top 100 search requests from a document that contains 1 billion lines of search requests."

My approach is to use unix `split` to chop up the document into smaller files, count the number of occurrences of each search term in each file with `array_count_values`, then reduce all those files into a single file that has a list sorted in descending popularity of each search query.

**EDIT**
For example

```
$arr1 = array('kurt', 'curt', 'kurt', 'dave', 'krist');
$arr2 = array('dave' 'dave', 'krist', 'krist');

array_count_values($arr1) // ('kurt' => 2, 'curt'=>1, 'dave'=>1, 'krist'=>1)
array_count_values($arr2) // ('dave' => 2, 'krist'=>2)
```

How can I combine the two to form the following array

```
('kurt' => 2, 'dave'=>3, 'krist'=>3, 'curt'=>1)
```

Comment: can you please give the $arr1 and $arr2 values and the needed o/p array?

Comment: Yes - please give me 2 minutes to write something up

Comment: You are taking the maximum of two ??? dave = 2, it should be 3

Comment: Document.. what is it? How you are working with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$arr1 = array('kurt', 'curt', 'kurt', 'dave', 'krist');
$arr2 = array('dave', 'dave', 'krist', 'krist');

$cnt_arr1  = array_count_values($arr1); // ('kurt' => 2, 'curt'=>1, 'dave'=>1, 'krist'=>1)
$cnt_arr2  = array_count_values($arr2); // ('dave' => 2, 'krist'=>2)

$res_arr   = array_merge_recursive($cnt_arr1,$cnt_arr2);

$res       = array();
foreach($res_arr as $key=>$val){
 if(is_array($val)){
    $res[$key]= array_sum($val);
 }else{
    $res[$key]= $val;
 }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
$count = array_count_values($arr);
```

Comment: This example works for a small data set, but what if I had a document of 1 billion search requests?  The requirement is to perform the map step on a worker node and the reduction step on the master node.  Assume the sum of size of `$arr1` and `$arr1` is greater than the amount of RAM on a single worker node, the size of `$arr1` and `$arr2` to be less than that amount of RAM when accounted for individually, but the sum of return values of `array_count_values($arr1)` and `array_count_values($arr2)` to be less than the amount of memory on a single worker node

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It will work,

```
$arr1 = array('kurt', 'curt', 'kurt', 'dave', 'krist');
$arr2 = array('dave', 'dave', 'krist', 'krist');

$array1Count = array_count_values($arr1); // ('kurt' => 2, 'curt'=>1, 'dave'=>1, 'krist'=>1)
$array2Count = array_count_values($arr2); // ('dave' => 2, 'krist'=>2)
$resultArray = array();
foreach($array1Count as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array2Count)) {
        $resultArray[$key] = $array1Count[$key] + $array2Count[$key];
    }
    else {
        $resultArray[$key] = $array1Count[$key];
    }
    unset($array2Count[$key]);
}
$finalResultArray = array_merge($array2Count, $resultArray);
print_r($finalResultArray);
```

Comment: @user784637:Did you try this?